# Injecting JavaScript Using Accessibility Service Enhance Web Accessbility

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-webview, accessibility

I want to inject js script into web page of mobile browser on text-field focus event or browser page click event, using android Enhanced Web accessibility Permission. 
It is possible and working with android app: "LastPass"
URL:https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lastpass.lpandroid&hl=en

I found permission details on android developer website but i did not found any code example.

Comment: Have you got this working?